# Cannot clone object '<keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x0000023DD4D5F488>'

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

My model-

```
#define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', input_dim=n_input_1))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse',metrics=['mse'])
```

Now I am trying to tune the hyper parameters by this code-

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)

# define the grid search parameters
batch_size = [10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
epochs = [10, 50, 100]
param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, 
cv=3,scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error')
grid_result = grid.fit(scaled_train,y_train_c)
# summarize results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

I am getting this error-

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-c6e1e39d878e> in <module>
      9 param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
     10 grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=3,scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error')
---> 11 grid_result = grid.fit(scaled_train,y_train_c)
     12 # summarize results
     13 print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    631         n_splits = cv.get_n_splits(X, y, groups)
    632 
--> 633         base_estimator = clone(self.estimator)
    634 
    635         parallel = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, verbose=self.verbose,

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in clone(estimator, safe)
     58                             "it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator "
     59                             "as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods."
---> 60                             % (repr(estimator), type(estimator)))
     61     klass = estimator.__class__
     62     new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)

TypeError: Cannot clone object '<keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x0000023DD4D5F488>' (type <class 'keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods.
```

I have no idea whats causing this issue. I am implementing a MLP for time series forecasting.

Comment: You should be using the KerasClassifier class, you cannot pass a Keras model directly to scikit-learn.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I couldnt understand...could you elaborate more?

Comment: See https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/